# Is the ring learning with errors problem still hard if the errors are drawn from some subspace?

Tags: lattice-crypto, hardness-assumptions, ring-lwe

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/x^n+1$ be the ring used in normal RLWE, which is linear space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with dimension of $n$, let $S$ be a linear subspace of $R$ which described by linear independent vectors $r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_m\in R$ where $m<n$. My question is:

> Let $s\overset{\$}{\leftarrow} R$, is it hard to extract $s$ by given $\{(a_i,a_i*s+e_i)\}_i$ where $a_i\overset{\$}{\leftarrow}R$ and $e_i\overset{\chi}{\leftarrow}S$ for some distribution $\chi$?

Or

> Is the distribution $\{(a_i,a_i*s+e_i)\}_i$ computational indistinguishable with $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_i$ where $b_i\overset{\$}{\leftarrow} \text{Span}(a_i*s, S)$?

You may assume $m\sim n$ if necessary (it is the normal RLWE problem when $m=n$).

Comment: You might want to specify whether $r_1,\dots,r_m$ are given / known to the attacker.

Comment: Hint: is plain LWE hard if every $n$-tuple of error terms lies in a known subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?  And how does this relate to your question?

Comment: @D.W. It can be known to the attacker.